# Proper ballast for UV-A fluorescent bulbs

Tags: uv, fluorescent-lamp, ballast

I have been tasked with improving a certain UV curing box product which uses Philips Actinic BL TL-DK 36W UVA bulbs. These are usually used in large bug zappers so I suspect that they usually are run with simple inductive ballasts which are integrated into the zapper rather than being an off-the-shelf product. However, there are other UV curing devices which use these bulbs. We want to use these with electronic ballasts for efficiency reasons, power factor requirements, and because they will get turned on and off frequently (so we are using programmed rapid start ballasts).

Based on the datasheet for the bulbs, they are essentially F36T8 bulbs, intended to operate at about 50V, 0.8 amps RMS. Presently, the design uses ballasts for T12 bulbs intended to operate at 100V, 0.4 amps. The lamps are indeed running at only about 350mA bulb current (with a voltage of around 50V) so the ballast is being forced to run outside its usual envelope and the bulbs are dimmer than they should be and the entire unit is consuming only about half of the power it should.

I tried to fix this by replacing the ballast with one intended for 30 to 40W T8 bulbs. However, instead of improving things, they now run at only about 250mA and about 56V.

Voltage and current are being measured with proper high frequency differential probes, high bandwidth current probe, and an oscilloscope.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? It would seem to me that if the voltage across the bulbs is correct (around 50V) then the current should be near the design current (800mA). Could it be that the bulbs have been damaged by being run by the improper ballast for a while? I have some extra bulbs on order and I will test that but I thought I would reach out to see if anyone else has any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to head-off any questions about LEDs - yes, I think LEDs would be far better in this product than the fluorescent bulbs and we will eventually probably convert to LEDs, however at the present time I cannot easily make mechanical changes to the product so I'd like to get the present fluorescent solution working as well as we can.

Comment: Swap the bulbs for regular F36T8 bulbs first…

Answer (score 1):

UV tubes generally require a different ballast than tubes intended for illumination. The tube characteristics are significantly different.

You'll have short service life and burn out the tubes if you don't use a ballast designed for the tube. It can also damage the ballast.  You can already see this simply by crossing T8 vs T12 tubes and ballsts.

And yes, it can be frustrating that there aren't electronic ballasts for **everything**.  I have several lights I'd like to silence.

Now, if you want the functionality of a programmed-start ballast, that is probably more achievable. Programmed start is about running the tube pre-heaters *for an appropriate amount of time* (rather than a fixed amount of time, as is done in rapid-start ballasts; or no time at all, as in instant-start) ***with the goal to get the light turned on ASAP because a human is waiting for the light***.  Mind you, if no human was waiting, then there's no reason to be in a rush.  You can get all the benefits just going back to the rapid-start approach (preheat for a fixed time period) and choose a time period that covers all bases. 3 seconds oughta do it.

Preheating is a completely separate function from striking and sustaining, so I don't see why you couldn't "step in front of" the ballast's normal start, and roll your own preheat regime.  At this point you've achieved the goal of programmed start.

An instant-start ballast uses an extraordinarily high strike voltage to get even the coldest tube started.  If you are sticking a preheat cycle in front of that, then you could stand to reduce the strike voltage.

---

Also note that fluorescent tubes are not in any way like resistors.  You seem to be expecting ohmic behavior out of them (double the voltage, double the current) and no, that is not how that works, and assuming it will lead to wrong-headed design.

A fluorescent tube, once the arc is struck, is pretty much a dead short.   The whole point of a ballast is to limit current.  So in that capacity it is more similar to LED, except of course for wanting high frequency AC.

I would also suggest you climb the learning curve using cheap commodity F32T8s that cost $3 each in a box of 30.